# Python: auto detect new files and expose functions as a service

Tags: python

i am looking for recommendations on best practices for implementing a service for which i can drop a file in a particular directory and the service will then detect the file and expose the functions in that file to the service...allowing users of the service to invoke the functions in that file.  I've read a few articles on various plug-in frameworks, but in this case, i can not mandate that the creaters of the files that will be dropped in a folder adhere to a common an interface.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can look for inspiration: https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the watch on your particular directory using [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/). You can use the paths of the files that triggered your filesystem watch to [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) them in python.

> i can not mandate that the creaters of the files that will be dropped in a folder adhere to a common an interface.

In that case, the file that was placed in that directory would need to perform some registration on its own.

Consider the following plugin file `myplugin.py`:

```
from yourAPI import PluginRegistry

def plugin_function():
    ... # your implementation


registry = PluginRegistry.get_instance()
registry.register("myplugin", plugin_function)
```

The registration of your plugin would be triggered by the plugin itself. This might also just trigger a one-time action.

The `PluginRegistry` would actually be quite simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks much.  I came across this article, which may me a possible solution as well: https://copyninja.info/blog/entry_point_wsme.rst.html.